# PHP Wamp server

Tags: php, wamp

Hey I have a database that contains information about different countries. I also have a html page where you can submit information about countries. Can someone help me to write a code that says that the information has been stored in the database instead of it just redirecting to a blank page?

Here is my html page where you submit information:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Sett inn land</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="geoinn.php" method="get">
        Land: <input type="text" name="navn"> <br>
        Hovedstad: <input type="text" name="hovedstad"> <br>
        Areal: <input type="text" name="areal"> <br>
        Folketall: <input type="text" name="folketall"> <br>

        <input type="submit" value="Legg inn informasjon">  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the page that you are redirected to when you click submit on the other page. This is the page where I want to have a code saying either that "The information has been stored in our database" or that it has not:

```
    <?php
    $tjener = "localhost";
    $brukernavn = "root";
    $passord ="";
    $database ="Geografi";
    $kobling = mysqli_connect($tjener,$brukernavn,$passord,$database);
    $kobling->set_charset("utf8");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Geografi</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $land = $_GET["navn"];
    $hovedstad = $_GET["hovedstad"];
    $areal = $_GET["areal"];
    $folketall = $_GET["folketall"];
    $sql ="INSERT INTO land (navn,hovedstad, areal, folketall)       VALUES('$land','$hovedstad','$areal', '$folketall')";
    mysqli_query($kobling, $sql);
    mysqli_close($kobling);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Please rename your question to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error($kobling))` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: The page is blank because you dont output anything. in the PHP script

Comment: *"instead of it just redirecting to a blank page?"* can you elaborate on that? Do you have a webserver and PHP installed on that machine? and how are you accessing this as, `http://localhost/file.php` or as `file:///file.php`? You are using a `.php` extension, *right?*

Comment: no idea why you're using GET here and that leaves you open to an injection a lot more.

Comment: @Fred GET is more open to injection...?! [Wat?!](http://memesvault.com/wp-content/uploads/Wat-Meme-Old-Lady-01.jpg)

Comment: @deceze I tend to think so, given anything can be passed in the URL's parameters.

Comment: @Fred Err.... you can also POST anything in the request body...!?

Answer (score 1):

Add some output and you will get some output. The blank page you get is the page that does the updates. You add the basic HTML page tags but do not output anything inside the `<body>`

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO land 
             (navn,hovedstad, areal, folketall)       
       VALUES('$land','$hovedstad','$areal', '$folketall')";

$result = mysqli_query($kobling, $sql);
if ( $result === FALSE ) {
   echo '<p>FAILED MESSAGE</p>';
} else {
   echo '<p>SUCCESS MESSAGE</p>';
}
echo "<p>Land = $land</p>";
echo "<p>hovedstad = $hovedstad</p>";
// and so on

mysqli_close($kobling);
```

> As Jay says,
>
> [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: missing closing statements there Smokey. Plus, `mysqli_error($kobling)` would say if something truly went wrong ;-)

Comment: Thanks Ralph @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome Smokey

Comment: How can I echo out what I just submited?

Comment: See amended code, for a very simple output of your inputs

Comment: Maybe you should start by reading [the PHP manual](http://php.net/docs.php) Its available in many languages